# Apache Timeout Directive not working on amazon ec2

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, timeout

I'm using Amazon Elastic Beans Talk which created an EC2 instance for my php application

The application takes minutes to process some work but found that the http connection get closed after 60 second

although the php script keep processing (maximum time limit set to 0) but the http connection get closed so I recieve no output

as example google chrome say

```
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.
```

I edited the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file on the instance and changed the timeout from 60 to 300

then rebooted the instance but the connection still getting closed at 60

what may be the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Know the problem

that was not an apached problem but was "Elastic load balancer" which closing the http connection after 60 seconds of no data transfer

yes this is boring and amazon don't listen to calls to set this higher

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=396594&#396594

Comment: Amazon just added support for configuring timeouts: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elb-idle-timeout-control/